# Whenever I try to append an image for reference it gives me a error and says it is not a library

Tags: image

[image]

Included a image of the error. If anyone has a solution I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is that path in the error line correct? You seem to have "swordInTheStone_downloadFiles_part2" twice in the path so maybe Blender is getting confused? Also, why are you trying to append an image rather than simply adding it from the Shift-A > Image > Reference menu?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply append an image, because images are no object types you can put in the scene by themselves.

Whenever you have an image somewhere in the scene in Blender, it is either used as a texture on an object's shader or used as a reference image placed in an empty or as a background image in the world or the camera.

If you just append it directly it has nowhere to go, it cannot be placed directly in the scene without an object, you didn't open it with the *Image Editor* or with any other open dialogue in some kind of texture node etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> for Add menu while hovering the mouse over the 3d Viewport and choose Image -> Reference. This way an image will be added as Empty type object. It will remain visible while in all shading modes so that's perfect for reference.

[image]

You could use a mesh plane with the image as a texture, but that way you have to worry about aspect ratio of the image. There is this add-on "Import Images as Planes", it comes with Blender so you can enable it in the preferences. It helps with importing images as mesh planes. They are only visible in Material Preview or Rendered shading modes, but you can then use the plane's geometry to start modelling or cut the image into parts or insert loopcuts and align them to features of the image to make snap points - that's sometimes very convenient.

Once you enable it in the preferences you get this option in the File -> Import menu:

[image]

It shows up  in the add menu as well:

[image]